# $4\times4$ determinant trick

Tags: matrices, determinant

[This link](https://web.archive.org/web/20171224102932/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/51968.html) uses a trick to find the determinant of a $3\times3$ matrix that goes like this:

- Put a copy of the matrix next to it, and now consider this as a $6\times3$ matrix.
- Find the sum of the **product of all numbers in the "first" diagonal** and **of those in the "second" diagonal** and **of those in the "third" diagonal**.
- Find the sum of the *negatives* of the **product of all numbers in the "first" *mirrored* diagonal** (from bottom-left to top-right) and **of those in the "second" mirrored diagonal** and **of those in the "third" mirrored diagonal**.

As I show here:

[image]

$$\mathrm{determinant}=aei+bfg+cdg-gec-hfa-idb$$

My question is, if this rule applies to other matrices of $n\times n$?

I have a faint memory of this trick also working for $4\times 4$ and $5\times 5$, but this link seems to imply that a $4\times 4$ has to be reduced to a $3\times 3$ first before this trick is applicable. Is my memory correct or are there no such tricks for larger $n\times n$ matrices?

Comment: Never heard of an extension of this rule (known as Sarrus's rule) to other dimensions. The fastest general method for computing determinants is Gauß's pivot method.

Comment: You'll be glad to see 3x3 in linear algebra drills, but 4x4 is just hideous XD

Comment: take a look at this http://mathoverflow.net/questions/105659/sarrus-rules-for-4-times-4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This trick only works for $3 \times 3$ matrices. The determinant of an $n \times n$ matrix can be calculated by looking at all the ways to choose one element per row and column, and taking the sum of these products with a factor of $-1$ for odd permutations. There are $n!$ such choices. When $n=3$, the sum will consist of $3!=6$ products, the ones that appear in your method. But when $n=4$, say, there will be $4!=24$ products, and you can see that there can be no simple trick.